# How to run this code faster

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code where the content is: filling formulas in cells that have no formula, then copy/paste values of entire row of those cells. I used 2 times "For Next", first for filling formula and the second to paste values

```
Sub CDPSKoCongThuc()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim RowNKC As Integer
    RowNKC = Range("CuoiNKC").Row - 1
    Dim RowCDPS As Integer
    RowCDPS = Range("CuoiCDPS").Row - 1
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    For i = 9 To RowCDPS
        If Cells(i, 9).HasFormula = False Then
            Cells(i, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(NKC!R9C12:R" & RowNKC & "C12,CDPS!RC[-6],NKC!R9C15:R" & RowNKC & "C15)"
            Cells(i, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(NKC!R9C13:R" & RowNKC & "C13,CDPS!RC[-7],NKC!R9C15:R" & RowNKC & "C15)"
            Cells(i, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(SUMIF(NKC!R9C12:R" & RowNKC & "C12,CDPS!RC[-8],NKC!R9C14:R" & RowNKC & "C14),0)"
            Cells(i, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(SUMIF(NKC!R9C13:R" & RowNKC & "C13,CDPS!RC[-9],NKC!R9C14:R" & RowNKC & "C14),0)"

            Cells(i, 11).FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-8]+RC[-4]-RC[-3]-RC[-7],0)"
            Cells(i, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-4]+RC[-8]-RC[-5]-RC[-9],0)"
            Cells(i, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(MAX(RC[-8]+RC[-4]-RC[-7]-RC[-3],0),0)"
            Cells(i, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(MAX(RC[-4]+RC[-8]-RC[-5]-RC[-9],0),0)"
        End If
    Next i

'Paste Values Formula

    For x = 9 To RowCDPS
        If Cells(x, 9).Font.Bold = False And Len(Cells(x, 1).Value) > 3 Then
            Rows(x).EntireRow.Copy
            Rows(x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next x

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write them all but you could use VBA to do the caculations and put the value in the cell so you don't have to paste the values or work with excel calculations at all.

For example...

```
  Cells(i, 11).FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-8]+RC[-4]-RC[-3]-RC[-7],0)"
```

would be

```
  Cells(i, 11) = Application.Max(Cells(i, 3) + Cells(i, 7) - Cells(i,8) -Cells(i, 4), 0)
```

You should also make a variable for each sheet and use them to reference the cells so that its clearer to read

```
Dim shCDPS as Worksheet
Dim shNKC as worksheet

Set shCDPS = Sheets("CDPS")  
Set shNKC = Sheets("NKC")
```

Then this formula

```
 Cells(i, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(NKC!R9C12:R" & RowNKC & "C12,CDPS!RC[-6],NKC!R9C15:R" & RowNKC & "C15)"
```

would become

```
shCDPS.Cells(i, 7) = Application.SumIf(shNKC.Range("L9:L" & RowNKC) , shCDPS.Range("A" & i), shNKC.Range("O15:O" & RowNKC))
```

Comment: When I just use 1 "For" to filling formulas it was run very fast, but with the second "For" i used to copy/paste values it's run very very slow. I dont know if combine 2 "for" into 1 does it faster and how to combine?

Comment: you dont need the second loop if you modify the first loop as i suggested

Comment: its the copy/paste thats slow not the for loop , also your copying the whole row , you should just copy the range with formulas or else the entire sheet, either would actually be faster

Comment: Thank you very much, I did as you said and succeeded. Now i understood your code, because my code wrote as macro (Excel Function) and you use VB Function

Comment: And how to use combine round(sumif(x),0) Martin?

Comment: just use  round(application.sumif())